# Blender scene suddenly gets brighter and I can't undo it

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I was trying to render my scene when I found that after a few rendering sessions the scene suddenly got brighter.

I can't undo it by lowering the emission of the object (if the objects have the emission nodes or any other bright nodes in the first place)

most of the objects use a toon shader but seems like even objects that are just colored and transparent are effected

[image: This is what it looked like before]

And this is what it looked like after most of the scene suddenly got brighter
[[image: This is what it looks like when it got brighter 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Render Properties* go to *Color Management* (last row) then check *View Transform* make sure it's *Filmic* instead of *Standard*.

[image: Filmic]

[image: Standard]